# hiding OpenGL symbols - using declarations

Tags: c++, opengl

I have noticed that libraries which load OpenGL functions hide symbols using macros, for example [Glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/):

```
#define glGenQueries glad_glGenQueries
```

It allows to avoid collisions in more complex applications which may link  to OpenGL through different libraries. I have a C++ library which also loads OpenGL symbols. Instead of using macros I put OpenGL function pointers in namespace, for example:

```
//lib.h
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>

namespace GL
{
    extern PFNGLGENQUERIESPROC glGenQueries;
    void load();
}

using GL::glGenQueries;

//lib.cpp
#include "lib.h"
namespace GL
{
    PFNGLGENQUERIESPROC glGenQueries = 0;

    void load()
    {
        glGenQueries = (PFNGLGENQUERIESPROC)glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte*)"glGenQueries"); 
    }
}
```

For some OpenGL functions I have defined using declarations, for example: `using GL::glGenQueries;` because I don't want to modify a code in the library which uses my library.

Does using declarations have impact on hidding symbols or `glGenQueries` from my library will be hidden behind a namespace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same names in different namespaces do not conflict, even if you use `using`. `using GL::glGenQueries` only tells the compiler that when you write `glGenQueries`, you mean `GL::glGenQueries`. It doesn't actually put the function outside of the namespace.